# Degree of permutation of hypercube

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra

Given $S_0\cup S_1=T_0\cup T_1=\{0,1\}^n$, $S_0\cap S_1=T_0\cap T_1=\emptyset$, with $|S_i|=|T_i|$ for both $i\in\{0,1\}$, what is degree of transformation that simultaneously maps $S_i$ to $T_i$ for both $i\in\{0,1\}$?

What is the maximum absolute value of any entry in the coefficient of transformation equations?

Note that transformation can be multilinear ($x_i^c=x_i\forall c\in\Bbb N$) since we seek to transform $\{0,1\}^n$. Hence total degree of transformation is at most $n$.

Comment: If $S_0$ is the intersection of $\{0,1\}^n$ with a subspace (e.g. $x_1=0$), then a linear transformation would have to map $S_0$ into a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. A typical subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ with $2^{n-1}$ elements is not contained in any subspace, so in general there is no linear transformation.

Comment: Ok What is minimum degree necessary?

Comment: Huge, no doubt. But I don't know how huge.

Comment: It cannot be more than $n$ since we are looking at only $\{0,1\}^n$ transformation.